# FullCalendar recurring events array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, recurring-events

I'm working on a recurring events backend for fullcalendar, and I've run into a strange problem.

My events are calculated on a page called events.php.  The calendar is displayed on index.php and calls the events from events.php.  My function on events.php outputs the correct string for the recurring events, but the calendar on index.php only displays the first event in each recurrence.  However, if I copy the string that the array produces and paste it directly into the events.php page and comment out the render_fccalendar_events(); function and inthe end of events.php that produces the string, the calendar will display all of the recurring events correctly.  From what I can see the output of the function, and what I'm pasting into the page are feeding the calendar on index.php exactly the same thing.  Obviously there is some difference though because it's not rendering them the same.  Any idea what in the world is going on here?

This is the events.php code:

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/local_i.php');
require_once('../../webassist/mysqli/rsobj.php');
global $wpdb;
$wpdb = new WA_MySQLi_RS("wpdb",$local_i,0);
$wpdb->setQuery("SELECT wpdb.id, wpdb.location, wpdb.name, wpdb.description, wpdb.recurrence, wpdb.start_date, wpdb.end_date, wpdb.repeat, wpdb.repeat_desk, wpdb.occurrence, wpdb.occurrence_desk FROM wpdb");
$wpdb->execute();
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
function render_fccalendar_events() {
        $_POST['start'] = (isset($_POST['start']) ? $_POST['start'] : strtotime('2014-09-01'));
        $_POST['end'] = (isset($_POST['end']) ? $_POST['end'] : strtotime('2014-09-30'));
        $start = date('Y-m-d',$_POST['start']);
        $end = date('Y-m-d', $_POST['end']);
        $readonly = (isset($_POST['readonly'])) ? true : false;    
        $events = fcdb_query_events($start, $end);       
        render_json(process_events($events, $start, $end, $readonly));
}

function process_events($events, $start, $end, $readonly) {
    if ($events) {
        $output = array();
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $event->view_start = $start;
            $event->view_end = $end;
            $event = process_event($event, $readonly, true);
            if (is_array($event)) {
                foreach ($event as $repeat) {
                    array_push($output, $repeat);
                }
            } else {
                array_push($output, $event);
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}

function process_event($input, $readonly = false, $queue = false) {
    $output = array();
    if ($repeats = generate_repeating_event($input)) {
        foreach ($repeats as $repeat) {
            array_push($output, generate_event($repeat));
        }
    } else {
        array_push($output, generate_event($input));
    }

    if ($queue) {
        return $output;
    }
    render_json($output);
}


function generate_event($input) {
    $output = array(
        'id' => $input->id,
        'title' => $input->name,
        'start' => $input->start_date,
        'end' => $input->end_date,
        'allDay' => ($input->allDay) ? true : false,
        //'className' => "cat{$repeats}",
        'editable' => true,
        'repeat_i' => $input->repeat_int,
        'repeat_f' => $input->repeat_freq,
        'repeat_e' => $input->repeat_end
    );
    return $output;
}



function generate_repeating_event($event) {

    $repeat_desk = json_decode($event->repeat_desk);
    if ($event->repeat == "daily") {
        $event->repeat_int =0;
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_day;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "monthly") {
        $event->repeat_int =2;        
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_month;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "weekly") {
        $event->repeat_int =1;                
       $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_week;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "year") {
        $event->repeat_int =3;                        
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_year;
    }

    if ($event->occurrence == "after-no-of-occurrences") {
        if($event->repeat_int == 0){
            $ext = "days";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 1){
            $ext = "weeks";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 2){
            $ext = "months";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 3){
            $ext = "years";
        }
       $event->repeat_end =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+" . $event->repeat_int . " ".$ext));
    } else if ($event->occurrence == "no-end-date") {
        $event->repeat_end = "2023-04-13";
    } else if ($event->occurrence == "end-by-end-date") {
        $event->repeat_end = $event->end_date;
    }



    if ($event->repeat_freq) {

        $event_start = strtotime($event->start_date);
        $event_end = strtotime($event->end_date);
        $repeat_end = strtotime($event->repeat_end) + 86400;
        $view_start = strtotime($event->view_start);
        $view_end = strtotime($event->view_end);
        $repeats = array();
        while ($event_start < $repeat_end) {
            if ($event_start >= $view_start && $event_start <= $view_end) {
                $event = clone $event; // clone event details and override dates
                $event->start_date = date('Y-m-d', $event_start);
                $event->end_date = date('Y-m-d', $event_end);
                array_push($repeats, $event);
            }
            $event_start = get_next_date($event_start, $event->repeat_freq, $event->repeat_int);
            $event_end = get_next_date($event_end, $event->repeat_freq, $event->repeat_int);
        }
        return $repeats;
    }
    return false;
 }

function get_next_date($date, $freq, $int) {
    if ($int == 0)
        return strtotime("+" . $freq . " days", $date);
    if ($int == 1)
        return strtotime("+" . $freq . " weeks", $date);
    if ($int == 2)
        return get_next_month($date, $freq);
    if ($int == 3)
        return get_next_year($date, $freq);
}

function get_next_month($date, $n = 1) {
    $newDate = strtotime("+{$n} months", $date);
    // adjustment for events that repeat on the 29th, 30th and 31st of a month
    if (date('j', $date) !== (date('j', $newDate))) {
        $newDate = strtotime("+" . $n + 1 . " months", $date);
    }
    return $newDate;
}

function get_next_year($date, $n = 1) {
    $newDate = strtotime("+{$n} years", $date);
    // adjustment for events that repeat on february 29th
    if (date('j', $date) !== (date('j', $newDate))) {
        $newDate = strtotime("+" . $n + 3 . " years", $date);
    }
    return $newDate;
}

function render_json($output) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode(cleanse_output($output));
    exit;
}


function cleanse_output($output) {
    if (is_array($output)) {
        array_walk_recursive($output, create_function('&$val', '$val = trim(stripslashes($val));'));
    } else {
        $output = stripslashes($output);
    }
    return $output;
}

function fcdb_query_events($start, $end) {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = array();
//    $limit = ($limit) ? " LIMIT {$limit}" : "";
while(!$wpdb->atEnd()) {
    $item = new stdClass;
        $item->id = $wpdb->getColumnVal('id');
        $item->location = $wpdb->getColumnVal('location');
        $item->name = $wpdb->getColumnVal('name');
        $item->description = $wpdb->getColumnVal('description');
        $item->recurrence = $wpdb->getColumnVal('recurrence');
        $item->start_date = $wpdb->getColumnVal('start_date');
        $item->end_date = $wpdb->getColumnVal('end_date');
        $item->repeat = $wpdb->getColumnVal('repeat');
        $item->repeat_desk = $wpdb->getColumnVal('repeat_desk');
        $item->occurrence = $wpdb->getColumnVal('occurrence');
        $item->occurrence_desk = $wpdb->getColumnVal('occurrence_desk');
        $item->allDay = false;
        $result[] = $item;
           $wpdb->moveNext();
}
$wpdb->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
    return return_result($result);
}
function return_result($result) {
    if ($result === false) {
        global $wpdb;
        $this->log($wpdb->print_error());
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
render_fccalendar_events();?>
```

This is the output of the events.php page

```
[{"id":"1","title":"test event","start":"2014-09-01","end":"2014-09-01","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"1","repeat_f":"3","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"1","title":"test event","start":"2014-09-22","end":"2014-09-22","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"1","repeat_f":"3","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-04","end":"2014-09-04","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-06","end":"2014-09-06","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-08","end":"2014-09-08","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-10","end":"2014-09-10","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-12","end":"2014-09-12","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-14","end":"2014-09-14","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-16","end":"2014-09-16","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-18","end":"2014-09-18","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-20","end":"2014-09-20","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-22","end":"2014-09-22","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-24","end":"2014-09-24","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-26","end":"2014-09-26","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"2","title":"test 2","start":"2014-09-28","end":"2014-09-28","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"},{"id":"3","title":"test 2","start":"2014-10-04 13:00:00","end":"2014-10-04 14:00:00","allDay":"","editable":"1","repeat_i":"0","repeat_f":"2","repeat_e":"2023-04-13"}]
```

This is the index.php code that's calling the events.php output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
            editable: true,
            events:  {
                url: 'events.php',
                type: 'POST'
            },
             error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
        });

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: If only the first event is rendered, it seems that you may have an issue in `process_event()` where it should `return $output;` but is instead `render_json($output);`. Can you make sure that, within that function, `$queue` is `true`?

Comment: $queue was false.  Changed it to true, but no difference in the end result.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work.

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/local_i.php');
require_once('../../webassist/mysqli/rsobj.php');
global $wpdb;
$wpdb = new WA_MySQLi_RS("wpdb",$local_i,0);
$wpdb->setQuery("SELECT wpdb.id, wpdb.location, wpdb.name, wpdb.description, wpdb.recurrence, wpdb.start_date, wpdb.end_date, wpdb.repeat, wpdb.repeat_desk, wpdb.occurrence, wpdb.occurrence_desk, wpdb.repeat_key FROM wpdb");
$wpdb->execute();
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
function render_fccalendar_events() {
        //$_POST['start'] = (isset($_POST['start']) ? strtotime($_POST['start']) : strtotime('2014-09-01'));
//        $_POST['end'] = (isset($_POST['end']) ? strtotime($_POST['end']) : strtotime('2014-09-30'));
        $_POST['start'] = strtotime($_POST['start']);
        $_POST['end'] = strtotime($_POST['end']);
        $start = date('Y-m-d',$_POST['start']);
        $end = date('Y-m-d', $_POST['end']);
        $readonly = (isset($_POST['readonly'])) ? true : false;    
        $events = fcdb_query_events($start, $end);       
        render_json(process_events($events, $start, $end, $readonly));
}

function process_events($events, $start, $end, $readonly) {
    if ($events) {
        $output = array();
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $event->view_start = $start;
            $event->view_end = $end;
            $event = process_event($event, $readonly, true);
            if (is_array($event)) {
                foreach ($event as $repeat) {
                    array_push($output, $repeat);
                }
            } else {
                array_push($output, $event);
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }
}

function process_event($input, $readonly = false, $queue = false) {
    $output = array();
    if ($repeats = generate_repeating_event($input)) {
        foreach ($repeats as $repeat) {
            array_push($output, generate_event($repeat));
        }
    } else {
        array_push($output, generate_event($input));
    }

    if ($queue) {
        return $output;
    }
    render_json($output);
}


function generate_event($input) {
    $output = array(
        'id' => $input->id,
        'title' => $input->name,
        'start' => $input->start_date,
        'end' => $input->end_date,
        'allDay' => ($input->allDay) ? true : false,
        //'className' => "cat{$repeats}",
        'editable' => true,
        'repeat_i' => $input->repeat_int,
        'repeat_f' => $input->repeat_freq,
        'repeat_e' => $input->repeat_end
    );
    return $output;
}



function generate_repeating_event($event) {

    $repeat_desk = json_decode($event->repeat_desk);
    if ($event->repeat == "daily") {
        $event->repeat_int =0;
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_day;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "monthly") {
        $event->repeat_int =2;        
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_month;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "weekly") {
        $event->repeat_int =1;                
       $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_week;
    }
    if ($event->repeat == "year") {
        $event->repeat_int =3;                        
        $event->repeat_freq = $repeat_desk->every_year;
    }

    if ($event->occurrence == "after-no-of-occurrences") {
        if($event->repeat_int == 0){
            $ext = "days";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 1){
            $ext = "weeks";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 2){
            $ext = "months";
        }
        if($event->repeat_int == 3){
            $ext = "years";
        }
       $event->repeat_end =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+" . $event->repeat_int . " ".$ext));
    } else if ($event->occurrence == "no-end-date") {
        $event->repeat_end = "2023-04-13";
    } else if ($event->occurrence == "end-by-end-date") {
        $event->repeat_end = $event->end_date;
    }



    if ($event->repeat_freq) {
        // explode skipped events string (from database) into array $list_of_skipped_events
        $event_start = strtotime($event->start_date);
        $event_end = strtotime($event->end_date);
        $repeat_end = strtotime($event->repeat_end) + 86400;
        $view_start = strtotime($event->view_start);
        $view_end = strtotime($event->view_end);
        $repeats = array();
        $counter = 1;
        while ($event_start < $repeat_end) {
            if ($event_start >= $view_start && $event_start <= $view_end) {
                $event = clone $event; // clone event details and override dates
                $event->start_date = date('Y-m-d', $event_start);
                $event->end_date = date('Y-m-d', $event_end);
                //if counter is in list of events to skip, don't do the next line
                //if(! in_array($counter, $list_of_skipped_events))
                array_push($repeats, $event);
            }
            $event_start = get_next_date($event_start, $event->repeat_freq, $event->repeat_int);
            $event_end = get_next_date($event_end, $event->repeat_freq, $event->repeat_int);
            $counter++;

        }
        return $repeats;
    }
    return false;
 }

function get_next_date($date, $freq, $int) {
    if ($int == 0)
        return strtotime("+" . $freq . " days", $date);
    if ($int == 1)
        return strtotime("+" . $freq . " weeks", $date);
    if ($int == 2)
        return get_next_month($date, $freq);
    if ($int == 3)
        return get_next_year($date, $freq);
}

function get_next_month($date, $n = 1) {
    $newDate = strtotime("+{$n} months", $date);
    // adjustment for events that repeat on the 29th, 30th and 31st of a month
    if (date('j', $date) !== (date('j', $newDate))) {
        $newDate = strtotime("+" . $n + 1 . " months", $date);
    }
    return $newDate;
}

function get_next_year($date, $n = 1) {
    $newDate = strtotime("+{$n} years", $date);
    // adjustment for events that repeat on february 29th
    if (date('j', $date) !== (date('j', $newDate))) {
        $newDate = strtotime("+" . $n + 3 . " years", $date);
    }
    return $newDate;
}

function render_json($output) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode(cleanse_output($output));
    exit;
}


function cleanse_output($output) {
    if (is_array($output)) {
        array_walk_recursive($output, create_function('&$val', '$val = trim(stripslashes($val));'));
    } else {
        $output = stripslashes($output);
    }
    return $output;
}

function fcdb_query_events($start, $end) {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = array();
//    $limit = ($limit) ? " LIMIT {$limit}" : "";
while(!$wpdb->atEnd()) {
    $item = new stdClass;
        $item->id = $wpdb->getColumnVal('id');
        $item->location = $wpdb->getColumnVal('location');
        $item->name = $wpdb->getColumnVal('name');
        $item->description = $wpdb->getColumnVal('description');
        $item->recurrence = $wpdb->getColumnVal('recurrence');
        $item->start_date = $wpdb->getColumnVal('start_date');
        $item->end_date = $wpdb->getColumnVal('end_date');
        $item->repeat = $wpdb->getColumnVal('repeat');
        $item->repeat_desk = $wpdb->getColumnVal('repeat_desk');
        $item->occurrence = $wpdb->getColumnVal('occurrence');
        $item->occurrence_desk = $wpdb->getColumnVal('occurrence_desk');
        $item->allDay = false;
        $result[] = $item;
           $wpdb->moveNext();
}
$wpdb->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
    return return_result($result);
}
function return_result($result) {
    if ($result === false) {
        global $wpdb;
        $this->log($wpdb->print_error());
        return false;
    }
    return $result;
}
render_fccalendar_events();?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
            editable: true,
            events:  {
                url: 'events.php',
                type: 'POST'
            },
             error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
        });

    });
  </script>
```